# Use react prop as import reference

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have this component, which I'm passing a string into. Let's say it has a value of "google". is there a way I could use this prop to refer an import in the img src parameter?

```js
import google from "media/icons/icon-google.svg";
import facebook from "media/icons/icon-facebook.svg";

const SocialButton = (props: { mediaType: string }) => {
  return (
    <button className={'continue-with-button ' + props.mediaType }>
      <span>
        <img src='Use props to set path of google logo or facebook logo' />
      </span>
      <span>Continue with {props.mediaType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + props.mediaType.substring(1)}</span>
    </button>
  );
};

export default SocialButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of ternary condition operators

```
import Google from "media/icons/icon-google.svg";
import Facebook from "media/icons/icon-facebook.svg";


<img src={ logo === 'google' ? Google : Facebook }/>
```

where `logo` is the name of your props

#### Switch example

```
const displayLogo = () => {
     switch (logo) {
          case 'google': return Google;
          case 'facebook': return Facebook;
          default: return ''
           
     }
}

    <img src={displayLogo()} />
```

Rather than importing images, I will usually put all my images in the `public` folder and then use `/image/filename.svg` in the `src` instead.

Comment: This is nice solution, but what if I had multiple types like: Google, Facebook, Twitter, Apple, Microsoft etc...?

Comment: you need to use a switch statement.